# Need help changing color in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Sorry for another stupid question, but I am wondering if there is a way to get the lines of code for changing the color of text the same way as in cmd. It works way better than trying to do:

```
set /p inputcolor=
if %inpitcolor%=1 color 1
```

because even if i knew how to use it with changing the background, i would imagine it would take a while.
Again, sorry for being such a n00b. just look at my name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p a=Please enter a color in hex: 
color %a%
```

Comment: i can't believe thats all it takes. I am so clueless. Thank you though.

Comment: @CodingN00B you can also change the background color. (don't tell anyone, it's top secret): try `color /?`